# What's the best way to model for various user access

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a rewrite of an app that has three categories of users
and I'm wondering about the best way to link them to the
authentication system:

In-House Staff,
Contractors,
Customers who interact via the app.

The in-house staff model doesn't store any address info. Contractor
and Customer have some common attributes  (address, phone number,
email, etc.) but they have completely different relationships to the
rest of the system.

In the current version I have discrete models for each type and I
manually maintain a link to the equivalent of the user profile table.
But I don't have model inheritance available in the current system.

My question is, do you have any general advice for this and how would
you link it to the existing Auth system, or is there a 3rd party auth
system that you'd recommend I look at.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is make the user profile model polymorphic. So that whenever you create a user you can add one of the user profile "types" check out: https://github.com/specialunderwear/django-polymorphic-easymode

its documented nicely and always worked for me.